# Construction of given quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There is given convex quadrilateral ABCD. And internal  bisectors of angle $<A$ and $<C$ intersect in point X. And internal bisectors of angle $<B$ and $<D$ intersect in point Y. And $<XAY = 90$ I'm struggling to do draw this construction , could anyone send me a photo of this construction?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, created with [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/) using a bisection algorithm to adjust the angle.

[image: Example construction]

Comment: Cross reference: the preceding comment was restated as a [full question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250881/35416). I don't have a ready answer yet.